# Architectural Advice on designing a WCF contract to expose a desktop app functionality

Tags: wcf, web-services, datacontract

We're currently working on exposing the functionality of a Windows Forms application via WCF services.

As an example, there is a form with multiple dropdowns in the desktop app. We would like to design a service that will allow a client to submit a request with all required values as if that client filled the info in the desktop app.

My question is:

What is the best way to expose allowable values for the dropdowns in the WCF service contract?

- Enums in contract ([Enumerations in DataCountract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx))
- Shared assembly
- Accept strings from client, on the server find the id or return an error

Note that some fields have a lot of allowable values (desktop app uses type ahead search).

How did you handle issues like this in your projects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the best way is to use an enumeration in the `DataContract` (first option you listed).

It's much more interoperable than a .Net assembly (if you expose a SOAP webservice through WCF, you'll be able to consume it from other technologies).

And you won't need to manually parse a string, an exception will automatically be sent if the client tries to use an invalid value.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a little concerned about maintainability of the Enum option. Any changes to the allowable values will require updating the enums and updating the WCF contract correct? I also would like to avoid manually creating enums for all the allowable values -if at all possible.